# how to delete fixed number of rows from a table with null values in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

following is my table

```
    CREATE TABLE tblnull
    (
      tnull integer
    )
```

for example `tblnull` contains `3652` rows all rows are `NULL`
So how can i delete only `3452` rows from `tblnull` on `PostgreSQL` and `SQL-Server`

Comment: `postgresql` or `sql-server` which one are you using?

Comment: Surely having identical rows is something to be avoided in a relational database, ideally every row should be unique hence why it has become good practice to enumerate rows. If you are keeping identical information would it not be a better idea to have a counter?

Comment: Also without ordering or selection how do you know you are deleting the correct rows? -even if they are all null for some reason

Comment: @Lucas don't get excited its just for a testing purpose there is no table or null rows in reality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, you can do this via the hidden [`ctid`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-system-columns.html) column:

```
DELETE FROM tblnull WHERE ctid IN (SELECT ctid FROM tblnull LIMIT 3452)
```

Comment: for [ctid](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-system-columns.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try following query:

```
DELETE z
FROM (SELECT TOP 3452 * FROM tbnull)z
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the number in SETROWCOUNT how much records you want to delete

```
    DECLARE @tableNULL table ([ID] INT)
    INSERT INTO @tableNULL ([ID])VALUES (1)
    INSERT INTO @tableNULL ([ID])VALUES (2)
    INSERT INTO @tableNULL ([ID])VALUES (3)
    INSERT INTO @tableNULL ([ID])VALUES (4)
    INSERT INTO @tableNULL ([ID])VALUES (5)
    set rowcount 3

while 1=1
begin
begin tran
delete from @tableNULL
commit tran
if @@rowcount = 0
break
end

set rowcount 0
Select * from @tableNULL
```

Comment: attempt is good but much complicated as compared to other answers

Comment: T-SQL queries is easier for less number of data and if we are going to deal with huge set of data this is the perfect way @keet..